# Is there any way to distinguish an HTTP request made from within a website in an actual browser from one made using code or some other tool?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, http

I have observed a scenario where a HEAD request made from a website I'm looking at in Chrome returns a session cookie, but the identical request, with identical cookies, headers, etc. made from Java code or Postman does not.

The call is coming from this JS: `$.ajax({ url: myUrl, type: "HEAD", crossDomain: true, cache: false })`.  Due to the latter two flags, the url looks like `https://myUrl?_=1433456890`.

From a browser, observing from the console, the request goes out and a session ID that looks like it comes from ASP.net is returned as a `Set-Cookie` response header.

When I cut and paste all cookies, headers -- including `User-Agent` -- and the timestamped URL from the request into some other tool, I get a login failed redirect.  I've tried incrementing the timestamp in various ways to no avail.

Is there any client- or server-side way to distinguish these two cases?

Is there something about that particular ajax/HTTP call that means it can't be reproduced by an arbitrary client with the appropriate session cookies?

Comment: What are you using as a user-agent?

Comment: Should have seen that one coming.  `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36` and others.